# How do I get an array from DB

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I've got a question.

I've got a table `table1` like this:

```
ID | email | first_name | last_name
1  | bla   | bladibla   | bladibladibla
```

And with that, I got another table `table2`:

```
ID | table1_id | name | value
1  | 1         | foo  | bar
2  | 1         | foo1 | bar1
3  | 1         | foo2 | bar2
```

**My question:** How do I get the results in php like this?

```
$array = [
    id => 1,
    email => bla,
    first_name => bladibla,
    last_name => bladibladibla,
    data => [
        [
            name => foo,
            value => bar
        ],
        [
            name => foo1,
            value => bar1
        ],
        [
            name => foo2,
            value => bar2
        ],
    ]
]
```

**My solution that works for now, but does not seem the best way to handle it.**

---

I have this now, but it does not seem to be the right way to do it, because in the first foreach loop, it's shooting a query to the db for every row in table1.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `table1`";
$results = $wpdb->get_results($query);

foreach($results as $result) {
    $otherQuery = "SELECT * FROM `table2` WHERE `table1_id` = " . $result['id'];
    $table2Results = $wpdb->get_results($otherQuery);

    foreach($table2Results as $table2Result) {
        // save all data in a new array just like I want it.
    }
}
```

Comment: You are looking for a [JOIN query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html). In this case, a left join would be sufficient.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins, I already tried a join query, but then I get duplicate values from table1.

Comment: You are getting duplicates because you are doing a `LEFT JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN`. Try `SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.table1_id`.

Comment: still getting duplicates @Anthony

Comment: Or, you are doing your joining backwards. You might actually want to be using this instead : `SELECT * FROM table2 INNER JOIN table1 ON table1.id = table2.table1_id`. If you are getting duplicates, that means the key on table1 isn't unique, or there are multiple records linked to table1 from table2 (in which case, duplicates are actually expected and should be handled after the query, not by doing two queries).

Comment: @Anthony, You're speaking my language now. Yes there are multiple values in table2 that are for 1 row in table1. As you can see in my table architecture. Now comes the next question. How do I detect when I'm done with 1 row, and have to start with the next row?

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "Select 
               t1.ID,t1.email,t1.first_name,t2.last_name,t2.name,t2.value
          From 
              table1 t1 
          Inner Join 
              table2 t2 
          On t1.ID=t2.table1_id";

$results = $wpdb->get_results($query);
$arr1=[];
$arr2=[];
foreach($results as $result) {       
    $arr1[]=['id'=>$result['ID'],'email'=>$result['email'],
             'first_name'=>$result['first_name'],
             'last_name'=>$result['last_name'],'data'=>[]];        
    $arr2[]=['name' => $result['name'],'value' => $result['value']];
}

$arr1=array_unique($arr1);
$arr1['data'][]=$arr2;
```

Comment: Then I suggest you improved your question. Look at how people are answering your question. I think they got the same Idea as I do

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `table1`";
$results = $wpdb->get_results($query);
$arr = []; // $arr = array();
foreach($results as $result) {
    $temp = $result;
    $otherQuery = "SELECT * FROM `table2` WHERE `table1_id` = " . $result['id'];
    $table2Results = $wpdb->get_results($otherQuery);

    foreach($table2Results as $table2Result) {
        // save all data in a new array just like I want it.
        $temp['data'][] = $table2Result
    }

    $arr[] = $temp;
}

print_($arr);
```

Comment: you can't achieved as you want from db ,In fact if you will join two table you will get the duplicate record from table1 whose id are marching with table2,

Comment: You can do one thing that you can store the whole object of table2 with matching ID of table1 in the table1 using json object or serialize array object like WordPress do with meta table

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array();
$i = 0;
foreach($results as $result) 
{
        $data[$i] = $result;

        $otherQuery = "SELECT * FROM `table2` WHERE `table1_id` = " . $result['id'];
        $table2Results = $wpdb->get_results($otherQuery);

        $j = 0;
        $data[$i]['data'] = array();
        foreach($table2Results as $table2Result)
        {
                $data[$i]['data'][$j] = $table2Result;
                $j++;
        }
        $i++;
}
print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You *should* be getting duplicates in the JOIN, since your example array shows that each table1 record is related to more than one table2 record. So doing multiple queries isn't going to avoid that. What you want, I think is something like:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 WHERE table1.id = table2.table1_id";
$results = $wpdb->get_results($query);

foreach($results as $result) {

    $table1_id = $result["table1.id"];

    $entries[$table1_id]['id'] = $table1_id;
    $entries[$table1_id]['email'] = $result["table1.email"];
    $entries[$table1_id]['first_name'] = $result["table1.first_name"];
    $entries[$table1_id]['last_name'] = $result["table1.last_name"];

    $entries[$table1_id]['data'][] = array($result["table2.name"], $result["table2.value"]);

}

print_r($entries) // the full array of table1 entries with the sub-array of table2 entries per table1 entry.
```

By keying each array entry to the table1.id, you ensure that even when they are repeated, the table2 entries get added as new entries to the data array, while not creating an new array entry for the main "outer" table1 record.

If you don't want the table1.id key on the array itself (and have a simple 0-based indexed array, you could re-index after you are done in the loop like:

```
$entries = array_values($entries);
```

Comment: Really? I figured it was the duty of experienced users to   call out bad behavior of other users. I figured "being kind of a dick" was the nicest and most efficient way to let the user know that they were being insufferablly rude multiple times to different users in a way that made their efforts feel meaningless. I consider myself pretty nice, and saying "being kind of a dick" less name calling and more of a critique of someone's current behavior. And I'm sure you became aware of this because he flagged my comment, rather than admit that he was being rude and got called out for it

Comment: And you can review my entire comment history to see that I've always advocated kindness and consideration, as well as keeping a personal and snarky voice. I will apologize for suggesting he was "being kind of a dick" when he apologizes to the three other users that he basically called lazy and illiterate when they offered their help. I think that type of behavior (along with tattle telling) is totally unacceptable for a user with a 1k+ reputation.

Comment: It's okay, I was being impulsive when I said he was being a dick. But felt I had to own it (since there was bad behavior and because I thought it wouldn't escalate). I'll keep in mind that things can avalanche quickly when the seal is broken.

Comment: Well I owe you a beer and an apology for implying you're a tattle tale. Guess maybe comment was actually crass enough to get me flagged by a third party. Anyways, from one testy jerk to another, I'm sorry.